Why was beta-plus decay not discovered at the same time with beta decay?
Nuclei rich in neutrons tend to undergo beta decay, emitting electrons.
Nuclei rich in protons tend to undergo beta-plus decay, emitting positrons.
Why was beta decay discovered far ahead of beta-plus decay? Nuclei rich in neutrons are more common in nature? If people discover beta decay and beta-plus decay simultaneously, people would have discovered positron much earlier!

How far apart in time are we talking?

1899 Rutherford coins term beta decay. 1932 Carl Anderson discovers positrons in a cloud chamber (cosmic ray generated). 1934 Curies observed beta-plus decay.

Apparently using P-30 from bombarding Al with alphas. So they had to make the nuclei that would beta-plus decay.

@JonCuster   The problem is why beta-plus decaying isotopes do not appear as often as beta-decaying isotopes.

Why beta-decaying isotopes are more common than beta-plus decaying isotopes is not a history question, see Why is beta negative decay more common than beta positive? on Physics SE:"Decays to lighter products where the energy conservation allows to give the final products some extra kinetic energy are more frequent... the inequality between the two types of the decay boils down primarily to the fact that the neutron is heavier than the proton which subsequently boils down to the fact that the down-quark is heavier than the up-quark."

Lets first look at Wikipedia:

Positron emission occurs extremely rarely in nature on Earth. Known instances include cosmic ray interactions and the decay of certain isotopes, such as potassium-40. This rare form of potassium makes up only 0.012% of the element on Earth and has a 1 in 100,000 chance of decaying via positron emission.

OK, cosmic rays were the cause of the positron that Carl Anderson saw in his cloud chamber. Then the named isotope is, as noted, rare on Earth (although apparently it is the 3rd highest producer of radiogenic heat in the Earth), and the positron decay channel is quite rare itself.
Wikipedia notes

Isotopes which undergo this decay and thereby emit positrons include, but are not limited to: carbon-11, nitrogen-13, oxygen-15, fluorine-18, copper-64, gallium-68, bromine-78, rubidium-82, yttrium-86, zirconium-89,[3] sodium-22, aluminium-26, potassium-40, strontium-83, and iodine-124.

OK:



Isotope
Abundance
Half Life




Carbon-11
None
20 minutes


Nitrogen-13
None
10 minutes


Oxygen-15
Trace
122 seconds


Fluorine-18
Trace
109 minutes


Copper-64
None
12 hours



Skipping the rest, what one sees is that these isotopes are rare at best, and decay very quickly. Fluorine-18 is perhaps the best known because of its use in PET scans, but all that Fluorine-18 has to be made on site at the hospital using a cyclotron and the O-18(p,n)F-18 nuclear reaction.
So, there aren't any positron emitters just lying around in normal materials waiting to be found. You have to go out of your way to be looking at cosmic ray interactions or artificially make them in the first place (as the Curies did).
In contrast, heavy elements on Earth have to be neutron-rich in order to be stable enough to have survived until now. But, when they spontaneously fission, even after giving off a few prompt neutrons, the daughter products are still neutron-rich and may well beta decay. So when you start focusing research on heavy elements, you get isotopes prone to beta decay for free.
